# Error on Transportlayer (No process on the other end of pipe)

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, process, shared-memory, sqlexception

Situation:

I have a lot of Microsoft SQL Backup files. The application should restore each backup-file with

```
RESTORE DATABASE {0} FROM DISK = '{1}' WITH REPLACE
```

Then I fill another database with some data from the restored database and drop the restored database with

```
DROP DATABASE {0}
```

If I only restore one backup-file, no problems. The data from this backup is in the new database and the restored database is dropped. But if i use more than 1 backup-file, i get this error:

German:
`Fehler auf Übertragungsebene beim Senden der Anforderung an den Server. (provider: Shared Memory-Provider, error: 0 - Kein Prozess ist am anderen Ende der Pipe.)`

English (something like): `Error on transportlayer while sending the request to the server. (provider. Shared Memory-Prover, error: 0 - No process on the other end of pipe.)`

Comment: The error occured when i try to fill a dataset with the data from the restored database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the below code just after restoring the database:

```
SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
SqlConnection.ClearPool(scon);
```